# list contents of directory in chronological in anaconda prompt

Tags: python, anaconda

I know that you can list the contents of a directory in Anaconda Prompt using the "dir" command.  How do you list the contents in ascending or descending order by modified date?  (Equivalent to "ls-t" in unix)

Answer (score 1):

```
dir /T:W
```

This will sort in the Conda shell by modified date/time, in order ascending.

Comment: This is all windows `cmd` not just Conda shell btw